# How to remove the lines from the matched string until the next match using sed command

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a following content in a file content.txt

```
cat content.txt
[testing]  
This is testing  
I want to remove content

[testing1]  
This is testing1  
This is contains testing information  

[dummy]  
some text here as well  
this is a dummy file

[source]
This is the source file
it contains data related to source file
```

I have another file "test.txt" which contains string which has to be deleted from the file "content.txt"

```
cat file.txt
testing1
dummy
```

I need every string should be read from file.txt and the same string should be deleted followed by the next lines until next string is found in the square brackets from the context.txt

The output should be as below:

```
[testing]  
This is testing  
I want to remove content  

[source]
This is the source file
it contains data related to source file
```

Comment: You asked a question, got an answer to that question, then commented that what you really needed to do was something else, then you accepted that original answer, then you updated your question to show what you're really trying to do which is something you would not use that answer to do. Not sure what you're thinking will happen now but my best suggestion is that you revert this question to what it started as and then post a followup question that contains your new requirements and new sample input/output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short **`awk`** command:

```
awk -v k="testing1" '/^\[/{ f = ($1 == "["k"]") }!f' file
```

- `k="testing1"` - key name indicating section to be skipped
- `f = ($1 == "["k"]")` - set flag `f` with `true` value on encountering section denoted by key `k`; otherwise - set with `false`

The output:

```
[testing]  
This is testing  
I want to remove content

[dummy]  
some text here as well  
this is a dummy file
```

Comment: Hi RomanPerekhrest, I have of list of strings which is placed in a file and each string will be passed to the command which you have given but I'm not getting the desired output. Here is the what I tried.  `for i in `cat file`; do awk -v k="$i" '/^\[/{ f = ($1 == "["k"]") }!f' testing; done`

Comment: @Sai, it works fine on your current input sample. Check wether you've posted an actual input content

Comment: @Sai it's extremely unlikely that you'll need a shell loop around your awk command and if you did that would be the wrong syntax to use for any shell loop. Update your question to show what you're **really** trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This type of task is exactly what awk's paragraph mode was created to handle:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '$1 != "[testing1]"' file
[testing]
This is testing
I want to remove content

[dummy]
some text here as well
this is a dummy file
```